# Laravel : Redirect the user to the same page after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a cart products page, if a person clicks on a product add to cart button they will be redirected to the login page.

After a successful login, I need to send the user back to same products page again.

I used the following way in login controller.

But it's not actually working the way i want. 
Means it redirect to the index page again, I have used the `return redirect()->back();` also..but doesn't solve the problem

```
if (auth()->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
             'password' => $request->input('password')))){
 if(Auth::user()->name == 'Admin'){
                 return redirect()->to('home');
            }
            else{
           //     return redirect()->back();
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            }
     }
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: return redirect()->back() didn't work?

Comment: nope..it doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

In this case `back()` and `intended()` will not work.

You can save last product page to the session. Very simplified example:

```
session(['last_product_page_id' => $product->id]);
```

And then use this data to redirect user after login:

```
if (session()->has('last_product_page_id')) {
    return redirect()->route('product', session('last_product_page_id'));
}
```

Comment: this might be out of the scope of this answer, but could you please explain why `back()` or `intended()` won't work.. any link that might help.

Answer (score 1):

May be Mezenin Solution is right But i solve it other way. (I took the concept from above solution)

As I'm using Laravel 5.4 ..I'm giving solution based on recent file directory..

I have changed the showLoginFrom controller which is inside `AuthenticateUsers` trait to this :

```
  public function showLoginForm()
    {
        Session::put('url.intended',URL::previous());
        return view('auth.login');        
    }
```

And inside my login controller I have changed :

```
if (auth()->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
             'password' => $request->input('password')))){
 if(Auth::user()->name == 'Admin'){
                 return redirect()->to('home');
            }
            else{
            return Redirect::to(Session::get('url.intended'));
            }
     }
```

And that's how when a user logged in, he will be automatically redirected to the previous page..